# Count active Cache sessions Laravel. (Advice Needed)

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Running into a problem here and been trying to find a solution for days now.
I want to be able to count the number of Online users in my Laravel application.

I already have build in a system for showing the online and offline user status in my application in the admin panel.

However i am trying to get a counter to just show the numerical value of online users.
Under is the code i used for showing the online offline status.
But now im trying to call while using the count(Cache::has('user-is-online')
However i cant get it working.
Hope somebody can help the way i can call  this.

For what i did manage to build i used the following:

Created middleware:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Cache;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class LastUserActivity
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);
            Cache::put('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id, true, $expiresAt);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Created controller:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Cache;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Show user online status.
     *
     */
    public function userOnlineStatus()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->get();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            if (Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $user->id))
                echo "User " . $user->name . " is online.";
            else
                echo "User " . $user->name . " is offline.";
        }
    }
}
```

Created route:

```
 Route::get('/check', 'StatusController@userOnlineStatus');
```

And i call it with:

```
 <td>
                            @if(Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $user->id))
                                <span class="badge badge-warning rounded-0 w-100">Online</span>
                            @else
                                <span class="badge badge-danger rounded-0 w-100">Offline</span>
                            @endif
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've unique key for the each user in the cache. You can't find it by partial key in your case. You can keep a counter like you're doing in the `userOnlineStatus` function and print the results after that. Look below.

```
/**
 * Show number of online users.
 *
 */
public function numberOfOnlineUsers()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if (Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $user->id)) {
            $counter++;   
        }
    }
    
   
    //Passing $counter to the view

    return view("your_blade_file_name", ['counter' => $counter]);
}
```

To access in blade file

```
The number of online users are {{ $counter }}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the code!
I am very new to Laravel.
So i will add this function under my other function in my Controller.
Is there any need for me to configure a new route to get this?
And what way would be best for me to call the count number from a laravel blade file?
Thank you so much

Comment: If you want to use it as a separate function then you need to configure the route. To pass this counter variable to blade file. I will edit the above answer to show you how to pass argument to the blade file. But you will find better documentation on laravel website about it.

Comment: Thanks again your help really solved it all for me.
I just asked another question here on the site and kind of hoping you can take a look again if you have time for this!